# Reading and displaying a RSS stream in Flex mobile

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, rss, dataprovider

First time i am using Flash Builder and i got a problem i don't manage to fix.
On this code, nothing is displaying in the view.  is used to be the delimiting tag in a rss file and  to have the title.

What can be the problem ?? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home"
        creationComplete="srv.send()">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="srv" url="http://www..../index.php?feed/rss2"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:List id="list" top="0" bottom="0" left="0" right="0"
            dataProvider="{srv.lastResult.list.item}"
            labelField="title"/>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the structure of your rss feed is, but for any that I've used the `dataProvider` requires the following path to the ArrayCollection of items:

```
dataProvider="{srv.lastResult.rss.channel.item}"
```